# How to crop pdf using Ghostscript (without entering manually Bounding Box)

Tags: pdf, crop, ghostscript, bounding-box

I need to crop a pdf-file to its Bounding Box.
First I calculate actual Bounding Box:

```
gswin64c.exe ^
  -o nul ^
  -sDEVICE=bbox ^
  input.pdf
```

the result

%% HiResBoundingBox: 156.350019 391.521011 445.919963 446.259010

I substitute into the

```
gswin64c.exe ^
  -o output.pdf ^
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
  -dUseCropBox=true ^
  -c "[/CropBox [156.350019 391.521011 445.919963 446.259010] /PAGES pdfmark" ^
  -f input.pdf
```

is there a way to substitute the Bounding Box automatically?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is called *command substitution*. Please refer to help by 'for /?' command

For simplicity I have separated answer into two files

First file (**getbb.bat**) get bounding box

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.02\bin\gswin64c.exe"^
  -o nul -sDEVICE=bbox %1 2>&1 | find "ResBoundingBox"
```

Second file (**replacebb.bat**)

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%b in ('getbb.bat %1') do (
call :Trim bbox %%b
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.02\bin\gswin64c.exe" ^
  -o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dUseCropBox=true ^
  -c "[/CropBox [%bbox%] /PAGES pdfmark" -f input.pdf
)
exit /b

:Trim
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set Params=%*
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ("!Params!") do EndLocal & set %1=%%b
exit /b
```

Comment: Hello
Thank you for reply! Unfortunately, it doesn't work :) Of course, I have changed 'gs9.02' to my version 'gs9.14'. Besides, I suppose getbb.bat contains an error: instead "ResBoundingBox" one should put either "BoundingBox" or "HiResBoundingBox". Am I right?

Comment: Don't we have to put mark "^" at the end of string
-o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dUseCropBox=true 
in file replacebb.bat?

Comment: 1. Whatever we find "ResBoundingBox" or "HiResBoundingBox" we get same line from output.
2. Yes of course ^ is missed

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in a DOS batch file and using drag and drop:

```
    "c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.21\bin\gswin64c.exe" ^
 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=bbox %1 2> CropBox.txt

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%G IN (CropBox.txt) DO Set MyVar= %%G

"c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.21\bin\gswin64c.exe" -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH^
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
 -sOutputFile=%1.pdf ^
 -c "[/CropBox [%MyVar%] /PAGES pdfmark" -f %1
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, no. You need to extract the information from the output of the bbox device, and send that separately to the pdfwrite device.

Your best bet is to write a script to do it.