# How to trim a PDF

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I am trying to trim the whitespace from a PDF. The PDF contains a vector text generated using LaTeX (XeLaTeX) [(example)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/osi5423eb282tyt/arched-text.pdf?dl=0)

I need to trim the whitespaces from these. I've tried using ghostscript and `-dEPSCROP` and while it works I end up with a pdf that is really bad quality.

Comment: Are you prepared to do some programming or are you only interested in existing command line tools?

Comment: I don't see how you can be using EPSCrop with a PDF file, that will have no effect. You haven't said **what** you've tried, nor stated the operating system or version of Ghostscript. Have you checked SO existing questions ? Here is one approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621237/how-to-crop-pdf-using-ghostscript-without-entering-manually-bounding-box

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=\temp\out.pdf -c "[/CropBox [137 4 222 19] /PAGES pdfmark" -f arched-text.pdf
```

produces a reasonably cropped file, you could get closer by using real numbers instead of integers.